# How to use type func(*dialOptions)

Tags: go, grpc

I am trying to use GoLang grpc library to make a dial. The GRPC.dial has a method signature like this:

```
func Dial(target string, opts ...DialOption) (*ClientConn, error)
```

and DialOption is a type like this:

```
    DialOptions func(*dialOptions)
```

dialOptions is itself a struct with other parameters but I want to pass userAgent string in transport.ConnectOptions which is another struct:

```
type dialOptions struct {
unaryInt    UnaryClientInterceptor
streamInt   StreamClientInterceptor
...
...
...

copts       transport.ConnectOptions
}


type ConnectOptions struct {
    // UserAgent is the application user agent.
    UserAgent string
...
...
}
```

How can I pass my user-agent in the along with the Dial function?

The library is linked [here](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/grpc/grpc-go/-/blob/clientconn.go#L98).

Comment: I guess, that I just figured out. grpc.WithUserAgent() function does this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a functional option as outlined by Dave Cheney here:

https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis

The essence is that you send in an optional function that modifies the `ClientConn` that is being created by the `Dial` function.  The library comes with a bunch predefined including one to change the `user-agent`:

https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#WithUserAgent

So your code becomes:

```
dialWithUserAgent := grpc.Dial("target", grpc.WithUserAgent("user-agent"))
```